# Rails 5 console needs readline 6 on macOS Sierra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, readline, macos-sierra

I have only readline 7 installed and I can't find a single way to install version 6 on macOS Sierra. This is the error when trying to run `rails c`:

> /Users/akashagarwal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': dlopen(/Users/akashagarwal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle, **9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib (LoadError)**
>     Referenced from: /Users/akashagarwal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle
>     Reason: image not found - /Users/akashagarwal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle

Comment: Did you try reinstalling ruby? I think when you compile ruby you get it with readline support. Your OS updated readline but ruby is still trying to use the old version.

Comment: @radubogdan are you on macOS Sierra? And which ruby version are you on?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not, but all of my coworkers upgraded and they didn't have any problems. Do you use rbenv/rvm or you have the "stock" ruby ?

Comment: @radubogdan rvm, I just stumbled upon rbenv, I guess I should use that instead. I'm currently on this: `ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]`. Is that what you're on?

Comment: I'm using `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]` but that shouldn't influence anything. Since you have a ruby manager I'd say go crazy and install a new version. I'm pretty sure it will use the new readline dylib to compile.

Comment: @radubogdan I'm new to ruby because of rails and I'm having a pretty hard time here trying to figure out the latest version of ruby. I did try `rvm install ruby-2.3.1_2` but it couldn't find it. That version is what `brew` installed it for me but still can't use it with rvm I don't understand why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125759/discussion-between-akash-aggarwal-and-radubogdan).

Answer (score 24):

I had a similar issue and solved it with:

`ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib`

source: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26658

Comment: That's a hackish way. You may run into errors which you don't understand. I updated my ruby version using rbenv and hence updated rails as well. Now rails needs the latest readline.

Answer (score 8):

A better answer that worked well for me:

`rbenv install -f 2.2.3 && RBENV_INSTALL=2.2.3 gem pristine --all`

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and this worked for me.
Add `gem 'rb-readline'` in your Gemfile and `bundle install`

And just type `bundle exec rails c`

Answer (score 1):

Jim Meyer wrote a good answer, but an even better blog post.

Specifically this is what should be done given that you use rbenv and maybe also homebrew to install readline: (cut from [Jim's blog post](http://blog.geekdaily.org/2016/11/macos-sierra-homebrew-and-rbenv.html) for posterity)

```
> xcode-select --install
[... popup dialog launches and you do the install dance ...]
> brew update && brew upgrade
[... many package defs update and upgrade ... ]
> for i in `rbenv versions --bare|xargs`; do rbenv install -f $i && RBENV_VERSION=$i gem pristine --all; done
[... much building of ruby and gem native extensions for each installed ruby version ...]
```